# Preferred way of working with ES6 modules and CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I have been playing around with the ember-app-kit project and I was running into some issues with ES6 modules and CoffeeScript keywords.

An example of the javascript I'm talking about is:

```
import Resolver from 'resolver';
```

and

```
export default App;
```

I have been able to bypass the coffeescript compiler errors by escaping lines with "export" and "import" with '`' backticks.

I was getting confused as to how to escape js like this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['pretty-color'],
  attributeBindings: ['style'],
  style: function(){
    return 'color: ' + this.get('name') + ';';
  }.property('name')
});
```

Does anyone know if there is a preferred way of working with CoffeeScript and ES6 modules?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can assign the component to a var and then escape the export of this var. Like this:

```
MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  classNames: ['pretty-color']
  attributeBindings: ['style']
  style: (->
    "color: #{@get('name')};"
  ).property('name')

`export default MyComponent`
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I don't care for the syntax as much, but I don't think there is much that can be done about that except for stop using CoffeeScript + ES6 modules.

Comment: Thank, It did the trick, but still expecting a more elegant solution